# Install vim-latex on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vim, latex, ubuntu-18.04

I just installed `ubuntu 18.04` on my machine and i want to install `vim-latex`. according to installation instruction of vim-latex website [1], I should extract some folders on `~/.vim`, and edit `.vimrc` but the problem is that on `vim 80` on `ubuntu 18.04` installed on `/usr/share/vim` not `home` directory, and when I followed all the procedures explained on the [1] on the folder in `/usr/share` directory, `latex-vim` does not compile and generate `pdf` file. Is there any idea how to solve the problem.

[1] http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=manual&title=Manual#user-manual

Comment: Have you tried the standard installation procedure on user directory ? Because the user directory only holds plugins and config, not the vim binaries (they can be elsewhere)

Comment: @Niloct usually `vim` was installed (I mean `.vim` directory) on `home` directory, but in `vim80` or `ubuntu 18.04`, there is not such a folder. where do you guess I can find it or how?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are going with the manual installation? The recommended procedure is to use a plugin manager, as is described [on the official GitHub page](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex).

Comment: @SébastienLavoie My problem is that `vim` installed somewhere else except `home` directory. and there is not `.vimrc`  in `home` directory. And if I install plugin in `home` directory, it can be sync by `vim` not installed in `home` directory. and which `.vimrc` should be modified? (`~/.vimrc` or `~/.../.vimrc`)?

Comment: Vim is _not_ installed into `~/.vim`, it is, in fact, installed into `/usr`. `~/.vim` is for _user's configuration files_, it is not an installation path. A package manager will generally not touch your `$HOME`. Same goes for `.vimrc` - it is not a file the package manager will create, it is _yours_, not system's.

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

As the other commenter added, vim binaries are not installed in the user home directory, only configuration and plugin files.

It's ok that the dir `.vim` doesn't show in your user home directory. Just to make sure it isn't hidden there, do this:

```
cd
ls -la .vim
```

If this doesn't list anything, then do: `mkdir -p ~/.vim`

Now install Vundle from these instructions that are quite clear:

https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start

And these instructions for installing the vim-latex plugin from Vundle:

https://vimawesome.com/plugin/latex-suite-aka-vim-latex